# Sign up role-back in case of a step failure

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have this signup custom policy:
I want to signup the user in the Azure AD and then invoke a REST API call to my managed server.
I want to fail the transaction (role back the user creation in AD) in case the REST call returned a non-O.K (200).

At the moment, the REST call fails, but the user is created in AD:

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>HTTP Request Technical Profiles</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="RegisterUserInIdcDb">
          <DisplayName>Register User In IDC DB</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://eabd-2a0d-6fc2-4383-5c00-5021-793d-42cb-9b57.eu.ngrok.io/api/v1/users</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
            <Item Key="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Cannot process your request right now, please try again later.</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_IdcAdminApiKey" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_orgUUID" PartnerClaimType="organizationUUID" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>

.
.
.

    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="RegisterUserInIdcDb" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="RegisterUserInIdcDb" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

What is the change that I should apply?

Comment: What does the `LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail` technical profile do? Is that a self-asserted page that calls an AAD technical profile to write the user to the directory?